# Ruby on rails error creating new app: parent directory is world writable but not sticky

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, bundle-install, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The first thing I did was setup a RoR environment using this tutorial. https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10 -I followed everything perfect, and everything was working great, even the tests along the way to make sure I did things correctly. This is where the problems start.

**After things were setup I kept following the tutorial to create my first app. I ran the command, and then you can see the rest, and then the error after bundle install**

What am I doing wrong?

```
    Pinocho2010@PINOCHO2010:/mnt/c/Users/joser/Documents$ rails new test_app -d mysql
  create
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/assets/images/.keep
  create  app/mailers/.keep
  create  app/models/.keep
  create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
  create  app/models/concerns/.keep
  create  bin
  create  bin/bundle
  create  bin/rails
  create  bin/rake
  create  bin/setup
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/secrets.yml
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/assets.rb
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
  create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.keep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.keep
  create  log
  create  log/.keep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.keep
  create  test/controllers
  create  test/controllers/.keep
  create  test/mailers
  create  test/mailers/.keep
  create  test/models
  create  test/models/.keep
  create  test/helpers
  create  test/helpers/.keep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.keep
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
     run  bundle install
--- ERROR REPORT TEMPLATE -------------------------------------------------------
- What did you do?

  I ran the command `/home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle install`

- What did you expect to happen?

  I expected Bundler to...

- What happened instead?

  Instead, what actually happened was...


Error details

    ArgumentError: parent directory is world writable but not sticky
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in `ensure in mktmpdir'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tmpdir.rb:95:in `mktmpdir'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/compact_index_client/lib/compact_index_client/updater.rb:29:in `update'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/compact_index_client/lib/compact_index_client.rb:64:in `update'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/compact_index_client/lib/compact_index_client.rb:55:in `update_and_parse_checksums!'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/fetcher/compact_index.rb:65:in `available?'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/fetcher/compact_index.rb:15:in `call'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/fetcher/compact_index.rb:15:in `block in compact_index_request'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:154:in `use_api'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:331:in `block in api_fetchers'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:331:in `select'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:331:in `api_fetchers'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:336:in `block in remote_specs'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/index.rb:10:in `build'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:335:in `remote_specs'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:82:in `specs'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:211:in `block (2 levels) in index'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:209:in `each'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:209:in `block in index'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/index.rb:10:in `build'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:206:in `index'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:200:in `resolve'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:129:in `resolve_remotely!'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:195:in `resolve_if_need'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:70:in `run'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:22:in `install'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/rbenv.d/exec/gem-rehash/rubygems_plugin.rb:27:in `install'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:102:in `run'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:175:in `install'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:27:in `block in <main>'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:98:in `with_friendly_errors'
      /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:19:in `<main>'

Environment

  Bundler   1.12.5
  Rubygems  2.5.1
  Ruby      2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
  GEM_HOME  /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  GEM_PATH  /home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0:/home/Pinocho2010/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  Git       1.9.1

      Bundler settings

  orig_path
    Set via BUNDLE_ORIG_PATH: "/home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin:/home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/libexec:/home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/shims:/home/Pinocho2010/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
--- TEMPLATE END ----------------------------------------------------------------

Unfortunately, an unexpected error occurred, and Bundler cannot continue.

First, try this link to see if there are any existing issue reports for this error:
https://github.com/bundler/bundler/search?q=parent+directory+is+world+writable+but+not+sticky&type=Issues

If there aren't any reports for this error yet, please create copy and paste the report template above into a new issue. Don't forget to anonymize any private data! The new issue form is located at:
https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/new
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
bundler: command not found: spring
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
Pinocho2010@PINOCHO2010:/mnt/c/Users/joser/Documents$
```

Comment: This is unlikely to be a Rails error. You're using OS X, aren't you?

Comment: @MarsAtomic looks like he's using an ubuntu VM in windows to me

Comment: No im using the new linux subsystem on windows 10, I fixed the issue thanks!!!

Comment: "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows is the name for the Linux Subsystem in Windows"... so it is not a VM but it is ubuntu.

Comment: @TeamAmplified I'm using ubuntu subsystem for win 10. So the provided answer is not a solution. I'm trying to install Vagrant and has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have missed a step in the instructions:

See: `parent directory is world writable but not sticky.`

`chmod +t -R ~/.bundle` will add the sticky permission that it expects.